# Importing react-dom without using it cause error after upgrading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

Just updated `react-dom` to version `16.5.2`, and all my tests have begun to fail dur to: `requirejs error occurred TypeError: Cannot read property 'unstable_cancelScheduledWork' of undefined`.

I didn't see any related errors on the release notes / any related issues using it so I assumed I've done something wrong..

When I comment `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` the test doesn't crash.. (doesn't pass either..)

Any ideas what could be done wrong?

Comment: Not sure this is related, but have you seen [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13694#issuecomment-423567167)?

Comment: @Tholle Very helpful!! I don't need to upgrade to `16.5.0` and above if I don't have time and scheduling dependency.. Do you want to make this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined by Brian Vaughn (React core team member) in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13694#issuecomment-423567167)...

> Yeah, the `schedule` dependency was added to `react-dom` in version
>   16.5.0. If you need to not depend on it for the time being, 16.4.2 would be a reasonable version to pin to.

... you can pin to e.g. `16.4.2` to mitigate this issue.